# IIS Application Pool, Service Account and MSSQL Connection

Tags: sql-server, iis, laravel-4

I have two identical Windows 2012 R2 environments. One is for development and the other is for staging.

For my server-side language I am using PHP and the Laravel 4.1 Framework.

I have a service account that I use for both environments to connect to our MSSQL development database. I set the service account to the application pool and assign that application pool to the application within IIS 8.5. I have done this numerous times with no issues. This avoids us storing the password in the PHP database config file within Laravel.

Now, the application I built is running fine in development. I can connect to the database using the method described above. I copied the identical code over to staging, again using the same environment and the same service account, but I get the dreaded:

```
PDOException
SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

Because it is working in development with no issues and because I have other applications on my staging box that are successfully able to connect, I am at a complete loss as to why this application can't connect in test. I spent hours yesterday troubleshooting with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are your sure you have assigned correct app pool to faulting application?

Comment: Oh yeah, double, triple, quadruple checked. It's weird because even when I assign a different application pool and instead of throwing a error stating that service account can't connect, it gives me the same issue. It's as if the application isn't tied to the app pool, even though it is.

Comment: How about connection strings? Are they identical on both dev and staging?

Comment: Yes. Both identical, hitting the same DB using the same username/password.

Comment: Are other applications running on staging env using same service identity for app pool? If not then you can try running this command. aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "YourDomain\YourServiceAccount"

Comment: Hello - there are no other applications running on either dev/staging using the same account. I create a unique account for each application. I did try the command in the prompt as was kicked back with a 'aspnet_regiis' is not recognized

Comment: Path for aspnet_regiis is C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319. Choose appropriate framework version. Alternatively you can use Visual Studio command prompt.

Comment: I ran it and I received a "Adding ACL for access to the RSA Key container... Succeeded!" What does this do? The application is still throwing the same connection issue.

Comment: The connection is trying to connect via the database config file. I added a username and I get the following error: SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'foo'. It seems to be ignoring the apppool and the identity assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue had to do with the ApplicationHost.config file. The other applications and app pools had an attribute of userName="" which the application that was causing the issue did not. I manually added the attribute and this resolved my issue.

```
<location path="Default Web Site/application-name">
<system.webServer>
<security>
<authentication>
<basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
<anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="" />
</authentication>
</security>
<handlers>
```